# How to disable animations in a Material-UI IconMenu

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am starting to work with version 0.15.2 of the [React implementation of the Material-UI](http://www.material-ui.com/), and am adding a drop-down menu based in a IconMenu, starting from one of their [samples](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar).  This is my current code:

```
render() {
    return <AppBar
        title="..."
        iconElementRight={
            <IconMenu
                animated={false}
                iconButtonElement={<IconButton><MoreVertIcon /></IconButton>}
                targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
                anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
            >
                <MenuItem primaryText="Refresh" />
                <MenuItem primaryText="Help" />
                <MenuItem primaryText="Sign out" />
            </IconMenu>
        }
    />;
}
```

As per the [docs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/icon-menu), I set `animated` to false, however menu opening is still animated.  How do I turn this off?

Comment: This behavior continues through 0.15.4.  However, I forked [trunk](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui) to attempt to fix.  It was labeled as 0.16-alpha, and what appeared to be the offending code from 0.15.4 was removed.  This may be a non-issue.